# R Save poLCA object to file

Tags: r, model, save

I have searched for ways to save a model output from the poLCA package, but can not come up with a working one.

I would like to save the modelobject my.model to file and the load it again in a new session.

Below is an example to work on..

```
library(polCA)
data(gss82)
f <- cbind(PURPOSE,ACCURACY,UNDERSTA,COOPERAT)~1
my.model <- poLCA(f,gss82,nclass=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
saveRDS(my.model, "mymodel.rds")

m<-readRDS("mymodel.rds")
```

Comment: could not get I to load with loadRDS. however readRDS worked. Thanks